# Ruby regex too greedy with back to back matches

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm working on some text processing in Ruby 1.8.7 to support some custom shortcodes that I've created. Here are some examples of my shortcode:

```
[CODE first-part]
[CODE first-part second-part]
```

I'm using the following RegEx to grab the

```
text.gsub!( /\[CODE (\S+)\s?(\S?)\]/i, replacementText )
```

The problem is this: the regex doesn't work on the following text:

```
[CODE first-part][CODE first-part-again]
```

The results are as follows:

```
1.  first-part][CODE
2.  first-part-again
```

It seems that the `\s?` is the problematic part of the regex that is searching on until it hits the last space, not the first one. When I change the regex to the following:

```
\[CODE ([\w-]+)\s?(\S*)\]/i
```

It works fine. The only concern I have is what all `\w` vs `\s` as I want to make sure the `\w` will match URL-safe characters.

I'm sure there's a perfectly valid explanation, but it's eluding me. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: "The only concern I have is what all \w vs \s." what does that mean? you could go with a negated character class btw: `[^]]` or `[^\]]` (should be the same) will match any non-`]` character.

Comment: Actually I thing it's the \S+ that is your problem, since it will match against the [] that mark the end of your things.

Comment: @m.buettner - I was editing same second as your comment below, but only because I saw your comment here. So thanks!

Comment: Updated my concerns. I like the idea of the negation character, which I couldn't get to work earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, thinking about it, just using `[^\]]` might not be enough, as it will swallow up all spaces as well. You also need to exclude those:

```
/\[CODE[ ]([^\]\s]+)\s?([^\]\s]*)\]/i
```

Note the `[ ]` - I just think it makes literal spaces more readable.

[Working demo.](http://rubular.com/r/aLVM2tFqHB)

Explained in free-spacing mode:

```
\[CODE[ ]    # match your identifier   
(            # capturing group 1 
  [^\]\s]+   # match one or more non-], non-whitespace characters
)            # end of group 1
\s?          # match an optional whitespace character
(            # capturing group 2 
  [^\]\s]+   # match zero or more non-], non-whitespace characters
)            # end of group 2
\]           # match the closing ]
```

As none of the character classes in the pattern includes `]`, you can never possibly go beyond the end of the square bracketed expression.

By the way, if you find unnecessary escapes in regex as obscuring as I do, here is the minimal version:

```
/\[CODE[ ]([^]\s]+)\s?([^]\s]*)]/i
```

But that is definitely a matter of taste.

Comment: This is superior, I think I'm just too tired to think in regexes right now . . .

Comment: So the negation character `^` actually applies to everything following it in the bracket? Very cool! Testing now...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the greedy `\S+` in this

```
/\[CODE (\S+)\s?(\S?)\]/i
```

You could try:

```
/\[CODE (\S+?)\s?(\S?)\]/i
```

but actually your new character class is IMO superiror.

Even better might be:

```
/\[CODE ([^\]]+?)\s?([^\]]*)\]/i
```

Comment: shouldn't you remove the first `\]` and replace the second `\S` as well? seeing that everything is supposed to be inside one set of square brackets